# How to select from BigQuery table that is based on nested json?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table created from json structure. I want to select field `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail` 
[image: n]

Please, help, how to do it?

Comment: I don't see a "json" structure.  I see arrays of records.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want `unnest()`, twice:

```
select ai.principalEmail
from t cross join
     unnest(protopayload) ppl cross join
     unnest(authentificationinfo) ai
```